# How can I configure swap over ethernet?

Tags: linux, ethernet, swap, ram

I have 2 computers and a patch cable, just a straight connection between them with no hub/switch/router/etc. I need more RAM and the other computer has lots of free RAM, how can I use its RAM as swap, over ethernet?

Both systems are running Arch Linux.

Comment: You can _try_ networking them to share a filesystem to set up a remote swap file, and even try stashing the file in `/dev/shm` on the source host, but I have a sneaking suspicion that trying to `swapon` a swap file on a remote system is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Is your Ethernet faster than your local disk?

Comment: Probably. Especially when the local disk is in use.

Answer (score 4):

First off, this is generally a bad idea.  The moment that the Ethernet connection goes down (or the system providing the swap space shuts down/crashes/reboots), the system that is using the swap space will die because it can't access the swap space.  You'll also see even more serious than usual performance issues when swapping (you would need 10GbE and really good NIC's to avoid this, at which point you're better off just getting more RAM).

That said, you've got a couple of options.  The simplest and most reliable in my experience for stuff like this is ATAoE (ATA over Ethernet) or NBD.  Unfortunately, Arch does not support ATAoE out of the box (it's a lot simpler to set up quickly than NBD, and only requires special software on the side providing the swap space), but NBD is supported.  You would need to create an in-memory filesystem on the system with lots of RAM, create a swap file there, and then share that out with NBD and tell the other system to connect to it.

Using NFS to share the file would probably work also, but is likely to be more error prone and less efficient.

Comment: Can't I configure the swap client to block until the swap server comes back?

Comment: The moment you're sharing RAM instead of disk space, that possibility goes out the window because you can't be sure if the remote system rebooted (and thus anything you had in swap is now lost), or just had an issue with the Ethernet connection.  The kernel is agnostic of this and will block indefinitely, but the moment the remote system comes back after anything but transient network issues, the first page swapped in will kill whatever program it was from because it will be empty instead of having the data that was swapped out.

Comment: I'd be ok with that.

Comment: Why create a swap file on `tmpfs` (I assume you mean it)? Why not just create a RAM block device with `brd` and export this device with `nbd`? Does `tmpfs` offer any benefit over `brd`?

Comment: The big one is that files on `tmpfs` can be pushed out to swap if memory is low, whereas blocks on `brd` devices can't.  There are also some advantages related to handling of memory fragmentation.  Alternatively to both, if Arch supports ZRAM block devices (not sure if they do, and can't get to my Arch reference system right now, the module name is `zram`), that would save space, and might actually perform better than putting the file on `tmpfs`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing the RAM of another machine via a swap over NBD

### host/server

Setup ramfs (if needed, if not just skip to nbd)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ram
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=16G tmpfs /mnt/ram
```

Config file `/etc/nbd-server/config`:

```
[generic]
  user = nbd
  group = nbd
[swap]
  exportname = /mnt/ram/swap
  copyonwrite = false
  prerun = truncate -s 16G /mnt/ram/swap && mkswap /mnt/ram/swap
```

Start NBD

```
sudo systemctl start nbd
```

### client

```
sudo nbd-client 192.168.1.3 -name swap /dev/nbd0
sudo swapon /dev/nbd0
```

Answer (score 1):

Been there, done that.
Mount a remote nfs file system. mkfile, mkswap, swapon.
It is useful if you want to do a native compilation on an embedded system.